# Garbage data for pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code, I expect to print all of the elements. But I get some garbage value after the output.

[output: 1 3 5 7 9 **6356752 15 2 6356884 4198653 1 12586264 12588288 4214784 6356816 -1 6356820 1946143264 1764509639 -2 1946142470 1946142496 12588288**].

But if I change,

> ar[5] to ar[6]

in the program, then the problem get solved. Why? (I am using codeblocks 17.12)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ar[5]={1,3,5,7,9}, *p;
    p = ar;
    while(*p) printf("%d ",*p++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pure chance. If you set the last item to `0`, this problem solves itself.

Comment: How do you expect to terminate your loop?

Answer (score 3):

With bracket notation, all unspecified values are initialized to 0. So here's the difference.

With `int ar[5]={1,3,5,7,9}`, you get an array like this (laid out in memory):

```
ar[5] = {  1,    3,    5,    7,    9  }
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
value   |  1  |  3  |  5  |  7  |  9  | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
index   |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  | (5) | (6) | (7) | (8) | (9) |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

where `(5)` means `ar[5]` can access it, but it's actually out-of-bound.

Since you don't know what could be in `???` blocks, `*p` is indeterminate (but usually non-zero), and the loop continues when it sees a zero in the memory. This can be *dangerous*!

With `int ar[6]={1,3,5,7,9}`, you get an array like this:

```
ar[6] = {  1,    3,    5,    7,    9        }
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
value   |  1  |  3  |  5  |  7  |  9  |  0  | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
index   |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  | (6) | (7) | (8) | (9) |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So when `p` points to `ar + 5`, `*p` evaluates to false and terminates the loop.

Comment: Nice visualization.